# Sylow $p$-subgroup of a normal group.

Tags: galois-theory, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a transitive subgroup of $S_p$ and let $H$ be a non-trivial normal
subgroup of $G$. I need to show that any Sylow p-subgroup of $G$ is also contained in $H$.

I know that any transitive subgroup of $S_p$ contains a non-trivial Sylow $p$ subgroup, of cardinality $p$ and use the Sylow theorems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $H$ is normal and all Sylow-$p$ subgroups are conjugate, once you show that $H$ contains one of them, you know that $H$ contains all of them. But since $H$ is transitive, the orbit of every element of $[p]$ is of size $p$ so $p$ divides the order of $H$, and so $H$ contains an element (and thus a subgroup) of order $p$. Thus, $H$ contains all Sylow-$p$ subgroups of $S_p$.